# Contact Form Not Sending Emails to example@domain.com

Tags: transactional, transactional-mail, contact-form

I've created a Custom Transactional Email for contacts page. 
It sends out an email if I use a example@gmail.com email, which goes to spam folder.

But if I use an example@domain.com email as contact, it does not receive any message. These mailboxes don't have a spam folder.

How can I prevent emails going to spam or how can receive these emails?

Comment: How are you sending the emails? phpmail? Try using smtp instead as many freemail accounts block emails with the phpmail header

Comment: where can i change that?

Comment: You require a module. This is the one I use: https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by changing PhPMail to SMTP.

Fix [Source](http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-magento-settings)